# Logging sql in nhibernate asp.net mvc application using nlog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, nlog

Just cannot manage to make nlog log sql queries generated by nhibernate in a asp.net mvc application.

Is there any example opensource application using nlog and nhibernate to look at (codeplex, github, bitbucket)?

Any article how to make them work together?

NHibernate 3, Nlog 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it finally. Used NHibernate.Nlog package, and did it as it is said [there](http://joseoncode.com/2011/05/04/nhibernate-nlog-support-in-nuget/).
Still had to create a separate NLog.config, and put a magic string  into the web.config. Fluent NHibernate doesn't want to expose this. I have no idea why.

Comment: @Mike_G any chance you could post your final working configuration? I'm dealing with a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17621706/8151 and have also tried the package you used to no avail....